# Django model doesn't show on admin panel when created through Celery

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am creating some dynamic Django models through a `celery` process. When I created these models without using `celery`, they appeared on the admin panel, but when I ran the process through `celery`, the models do not appear on the admin page. I know the model are created because when I run `makemigrations` after, it does recognize the newly created models. My code is something like this:

**signals.py**

```
@disable_for_loaddata
def email_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    from email.tasks import update_email
    update_email.delay(instance.pk)
```

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def update_email(id):
    from email.views import save_email
    save_email(id)
```

**views.py**

```
def save_email(id):
    from email.models import EmailType
    instance = EmailType.objects.get(pk=id)  
    model = type(instance.__str__(), (Email,), attrs)

    admin.site.register(model, admin_opts)
    reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
    clear_url_caches()

    call_command('makemigrations')
    call_command('migrate')
```

Can anyone point out why this makes the model not show up on the admin panel?

Comment: @hansTheFranz are you suggesting to delete `admin.site.register(model, admin_opts)`?

Comment: what's the value of `admin_opts` in `admin.site.register(model, admin_opts)`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule it is a bunch of admin field options like this: 
`class BaseEmail(admin.ModelAdmin): 
        fields = (...)` to change the fields that are displayed on the admin page

Comment: I think you want to ensure that `model` is a child class of `models.Model`. As you already mentioned, `admin_opts` is a child class of `admin.ModelAdmin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up tackling this issue was by dividing the tasks I was giving to celery in 2. First task is creating the models dynamically and second is to add objects to those models. I did the creation of the dynamic models synchronously. Right away I call my celery function and the creation of the objects under the new model is done through celery.

One thing to note, is that when you create objects of the dynamic model type, you will get an error saying the said model doesn't exist. What you should do is to create the model again in your celery function.